# Reporting in Oracle 11g Express

Tags: sql, oracle, report

Using Oracle 11g Express edition. For a project I need to have a document that contains all of my necessary SQL statements and outputs (a report of these), and an SQL file that contains ALL of my SQL statements that I have written during the project.

How do you set up these reports reporting into these documents ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize spooling capability of SQLPlus

```
SQL>-- turn on writing query result to a file
SQL>spool c:\temp\myorareport.txt;

SQL>-- enter and execute your queries
SQL>select * from employees;

SQL>-- turn off spooling
SQL>spool off;
```

Comment: @Jim You're welcome. Please consider to post your own answer also, so that other may benefit from it.